# Is the packing density of an ellipse the same as that of a circle?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, packing-problem

It is well-known that the densest packing of circles in the plane is the close hexagonal packing, with a density of $\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}6\approx0.9069$:

[image]

By applying an affine transformation, we obtain a packing of ellipses with the same density:

[image]

However, not every ellipse packing arises from such a transformation, as we can rotate the ellipses at different angles. So it does not follow that the ellipse must have the same packing density.

**Are there any ellipses which have a higher packing density than the circle?**

I realize this question may be very difficult to answer in the affirmative, given the subtlety and difficulty of most packing problems, but I am curious to hear of bounds on the problem (possibly as a function of the aspect ratio) and expert opinions on the likely answer, if nothing else.

It is worth noting that in the three-dimensional case, the packing density of an ellipsoid *can* be higher than that of the sphere, with some ellipsoids having packing densities of at least $0.7585\ldots$ compared to the sphere's $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{18}}\approx0.7405$ (see [Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipsoidPacking.html), [J. Wills](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematika/article/abs/an-ellipsoid-packing-in-e3-of-unexpected-high-density/)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some further investigation reveals that ellipses do indeed have the same packing density as circles, though I hadn't seen it explicitly stated anywhere before so it seems worth leaving this question up for future readers.

In L. Fejes Tóth's 1949 paper [*Some packing and covering theorems*](http://acta.bibl.u-szeged.hu/13588/1/math_012_pars_a_062-067.pdf), it is noted that a consequence of Theorem $1$ is that every centrally symmetric convex set has a packing density equal to its translational or lattice packing density, from which the desired result follows: we can assume that an optimal ellipse packing uses only translations, then apply an affine transformation to yield a circle packing of the same density, which could be improved were it any lower than $\pi\sqrt{3}/6$. (He mentions in footnote 8 that this result may have been independently given in an October 1949 lecture of K. Mahler.)

However, Tóth notes that there may still be non-lattice packings that attain the same density, so one can still ask whether there exist nontrivial deviations from the hexagonal packing with an optimal $\pi\sqrt{3}/6$ density. (I do not know whether this is the case, though I would be surprised to find it was true.)

Comment: Wait, doesn't that mean that the answer is **no**--i.e., no ellipse has a packing density exceeding that of the circle?  Or am I missing something?  Oh; you are answering the question in your title, but the question in bold in your question body is the opposite.

Comment: Ah, I suppose there is some unfortunate wording in the original question. I was answering the question in the title ("are they the same"), which is the negation of the bolded question in the body of the post. I will edit to make the answer clearer - thanks for the catch!